# AWS CodeDeploy: STRING_VALUE can not be converted to an Integer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

Using AWS CodePipeline and setting a Source, Build and passing `taskdef.json` and `appspec.yaml` as artifacts, the deployment action `Amazon ECS (Blue/Green)` will fail with the error:

```
STRING_VALUE can not be converted to an Integer
```

This error does not specify where this error happens and therefore it is not possible to fix.

For reference, the files look like this:

```yaml
# appspec.yaml
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - TargetService:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties:
        TaskDefinition: <TASK_DEFINITION>
        LoadBalancerInfo:
          ContainerName: "my-project"
          ContainerPort: 3000
```

```json
// taskdef.json
{
  "family": "my-project-web",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/ecsTaskRole-role",
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole-web",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "256",
  "memory": "512",
  "containerDefinitions":
  [
    {
       "name": "my-project",
       "memory": "512",
       "image": "01234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-project:a09b7d81",
       "environment": [],
       "secrets":
       [
         {
           "name": "APP_ENV",
           "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:1234567890:secret:web/my-project-NBcsLj:APP_ENV::"
         },
         {
            "name": "PORT",
            "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:1234567890:secret:web/my-project-NBcsLj:PORT::"
         },
         {
           "name": "APP_NAME",
           "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:1234567890:secret:web/my-project-NBcsLj:APP_NAME::"
         },
         {
           "name": "LOG_CHANNEL",
           "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:1234567890:secret:web/my-project-NBcsLj:LOG_CHANNEL::"
         },
         {
           "name": "APP_KEY",
           "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:1234567890:secret:web/my-project-NBcsLj:APP_KEY::"
         },
         { 
           "name": "APP_DEBUG",
           "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:1234567890:secret:web/my-project-NBcsLj:APP_DEBUG::"
         }
       ],
       "essential": true,
       "logConfiguration":
       {
         "logDriver": "awslogs",
         "options":
         {
           "awslogs-group": "",
           "awslogs-region": "",
           "awslogs-stream-prefix": ""
         }
       },
       "portMappings":
       [
         {
           "hostPort": 3000,
           "protocol": "tcp",
           "containerPort": 3000
         }
       ],
       "entryPoint": [ "web" ], 
       "command": []
     }
   ],
   "requiresCompatibilities": [ "FARGATE", "EC2" ],
   "tags":
   [
     {
       "key": "project",
       "value": "my-project"
     }
   ]
}
```

Any insights on this issue are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the following guide that outlines the supported data type for each parameter: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html. It appears that you've provided a string where an integer is expected.

If I was to guess, looking at the above, the value for `memory` under `containerDefinitions` should be an integer not a string: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_memory

Comment: Thank you @norman for pointing that! Interestingly AWS sets same memory as string in another section outside of this same file, which mislead me. Keep Rocking!

Comment: The API reference provides a more thorough description of every field and its type: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_TaskDefinition.html